# `block in load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Pry::Command::ExitAll (NameError) when launching rails server and console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am starting a new project on rails and can't launch rails server or console because of an error with the 'pry' gem (i think.. starting to doubt now)

My gemfile looks like this :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'


gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2', '>= 6.0.2.2'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'simple_form'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'

end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Pry gems versions:

```
pry (0.13.0)
pry-byebug (3.9.0)
pry-rails (0.3.9)
```

Whenever i try to launch the console or server, this is what i get:

```
from /Users/maudecouturier/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:9:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:80:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:59:in `load_missing_constant'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/pry-byebug/commands/exit_all.rb:7:in `<module:PryByebug>'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/pry-byebug/commands/exit_all.rb:3:in `<main>'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/pry-byebug/commands.rb:12:in `<main>'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/pry-byebug/cli.rb:5:in `<main>'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.13.0/lib/pry/plugins.rb:55:in `load_cli_options'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.13.0/lib/pry/cli.rb:40:in `each'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.13.0/lib/pry/cli.rb:40:in `add_plugin_options'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.13.0/lib/pry/cli.rb:134:in `<main>'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.13.0/lib/pry.rb:78:in `<main>'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-byebug-3.8.0/lib/pry-byebug.rb:3:in `<main>'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `each'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `block in require'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
  from /Users/mcout/code/mcout/marguine/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from /Users/mcout/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I tried uninstalling pry and reinstalling it without success.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Whats on `/config/application.rb:7`?

Comment: ```require_relative 'boot'
require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Proj
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.generators do |generate|
      generate.assets false
      generate.helper false
      generate.test_framework :test_unit, fixture: false
    end
  end
end```

Answer (score 1):

@mcout I had this myself nowadays and i fixed it with leveling up the version of `psy-byebug` in my gemfile to at least 3.9.0

After giving it a `bundle install` it worked ...

Maybe this helps somebody in these days with the same error...